# How to post cross domain data and get a response using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, post, cross-domain

Im trying to create a bookmarklet that allows users to post a lot of cross domain data to a php script and get a response from the php script using jquery. What is the best way to do this

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make your PHP script to parse JSON data? You can post JSON via jQuery to your PHP script and then just parse that. `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` would work here..

Answer (score 3):

Your best shot will be to use **[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)**:

> JSONP or "JSON with padding" is a complement to the base JSON data format, a pattern of usage allowing a page to request data from a server in a different domain. JSONP is a solution to this problem, forming an alternative to a more recent method called Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

jQuery implements JSONP. Try and test this code:

```
$.ajax( {
  url: 'http://…',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  complete: function(xmlHttpReq, textStatus) {…}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out [JavaScript: Use a Web Proxy for Cross-Domain XMLHttpRequest Calls](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tricky because Cross Site Scripting gets blocked by most browsers.  My solution was to write the data to a file and then access that file from php.  Pass the data through a file in other words.