# Connecting to PHP on different domain to HTML with Jquery (AJAX)

Tags: php, jquery, cross-domain

Trying to receive a response from a PHP which is on a different domain to my HTML:

```
 $.get('getstate.php', {
                email: $('#game-email').val(),
                country: 'DE',
                lang: lang,
                source: 'promotion'
            }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
             });
```

In chrome I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load ..... Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

Comment: surely if you're trying to get `getstate.php` it should be the full path of the url if its located on another domain

Comment: the fastest way is to proxy the request through the local php server and a curl request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google shows me that this has been answered here many times before... [It's not possible with ajax for security reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), so you will have to either

1. call another domain from within your PHP script, or
2. look at [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334666/how-to-post-cross-domain-data-and-get-a-response-using-php-and-jquery?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try dataType: 'jsonp'
    `$`.get('page.php, {}, callback, "jsonp");

Comment: the server needs to support jsonp obviously

Comment: is there any other way without the server having to support jsonp?

Comment: @1937021 Do you has access to that server?

Answer (score 0):

a simple PHP proxy from http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

```
<?php
// Set your return content type
header('Content-type: application/xml');

// Website url to open
$daurl = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/jQueryHowto';

// Get that website's content
$handle = fopen($daurl, "r");

// If there is something, read and return
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        echo $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```